# Numerical evaluation in sympy

Tags: python

In Sympy, for sqrt(3)- it gives me sqrt(3)(which is not evaluated)
Now for sqrt(3.2)- it gives me 1.78885438199983 (which is evaluated)

Is there any way it is left ***unevaluated***?
I mean for sqrt(3.2) should give me sqrt(3.2) (in symbolic form) similarly for 1./3 it should give the same symbolic expression as 1/3
[image]

Comment: What about `sqrt(Rational(16, 5))`?

Comment: Output:   mpf('1.7888543819998317')